# Java array[][] working out

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I was hoping someone can help me, I have an exam in a couple weeks and I have come across this question whilst practicing some past papers.

```
int[][] x = { { 1, 6 }, { 7, 3 }, { 7, 6 } };
double b = x[x[0][0]][1];
```

The question asks for the answer `b` will produce, I have simulated it on eclipse and it gives the answer `3.0`. However, I am really not sure how to get this answer? If anyone can explain this to me I would be really grateful!

Comment: Start with `x[0][0]`; look at `x` (it's the very first element, so `1`). Thus `double b = x[1][1]`. There we have an `int` three. That gets widened to double, and thus it is `3.0`

Comment: Or consider that `x[0] = { 1, 6 }`, `x[1] = { 7, 3 }` &c.

Comment: You also may want to rephrase the title, as all I could think of is an array doing lifts... :d

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia [Hans und Franz](https://youtu.be/S-GLO_PydqU) are *standing* by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down into parts:

Initial:

```
int[][] x = { { 1, 6 }, { 7, 3 }, { 7, 6 } };
double b = x[x[0][0]][1];
```

- The inner `x[0]` in `x[`**`x[0]`**`[0]][1]` is `{ 1, 6 }`
- The inner `x[0][0]` in `x[`**`x[0][0]`**`][1]` is therefore `1`
- So now we have `x[1][1]`
- `x[1]` is `{ 7, 3 }`
- And `x[1][1]` is therefore `3`

Conclusion: `x[x[0][0]][1] =`**`3`**

---

EDIT: In addition, `b` is a double, so it implicitly casts the int 3 to double, which makes the result `b = 3.0` instead.

In the [Java Language Specifications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) you can find more information about how implicit casts, widening conversions, loss of precision, etc. works in Java.

Answer (score 0):

View the problem like this

x[0][0] value is 1.0

So the problem simplified is x[1][1] = 3.0

> [1 ,6]
>
> [7, 3]
>
> [7, 6]

Keep in mind Java 2d arrays are [y][x]

Answer (score -1):

Read  `x[x[0][0]][1];` as  x**[**x[0][0]**]****[**1**]**;
where `x[0][0]` is 1 
So,  `x[x[0][0]][1]`will be
 `x[1][1]` = `3.0` as it is double.

Comment: Oh wow! First you answered a question which shouldn't be answered., Then, you answered it wrong!